# Remove default top margins from nested inline-blocks

Tags: css, margin, default

Preparing a website navbar, I thought of creating hover effects over tab like Android does it, i.e. a top border displays over a tab when you hover over the tab.

The problem is, these navbar tabs are nested in a container div, and for some reason, the navbar tabs have a slight margin, even though I haven't specified one explicitly. So, the top border which I want, is not perfectly aligned to the top of the window.

I tried the ususal workarounds: setting `font-size:0` in the parent, using `vertical-align:top` and `margin-top:-4px`, but non of those seem to work perfect.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A3nEq/

Notice a thin black line between the absolute top and the white top border. I have to get rid of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `border: 2px solid transparent;` from your #headContainer div.

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/A3nEq/1/**

Comment: Oh! Didnt think that this was causing this problem!! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the border from #headContainer.